# How to install certificate in local machine trusted root certification Authorities using inno setup

Tags: inno-setup

I am using  inno setup to create a setup for my  .net Application for  windows .  I have to install a .pfx file in Trusted Root Certification authorities .  How can i do this ?

I have tried  the following line in Run section

```
[Run]
Filename: "certutil.exe"; Parameters: "-enterprise  -addstore ""Root"" {app}\Application\rootCert.cer"; Flags: runhidden; StatusMsg: "Adding trusted publisher..."
```

This is .cer file  and it install in user  Trusted Root certification but i want in  Local Computer  and alternative for .pfx file

Thanks

Comment: actually i just want to install .pfx file  through inno setup

Comment: The link you mentioned , when i run  the command manually  it is  installing properly . certutil -f -user  -enterprise -importpfx TrustedPeople "location\rootCert.pfx" .  How to execute this   from inno setup

Comment: The same way you run `certutil` in the script you have in your question....